# Google Cloud Storage makes browser download image

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

After uploading a file to a GCS bucket, that is publically readbale, when I access the file directly (http://storage.googleapis.com//image.png) the browser (Chrome) downloads the file, instead of displaying it.

In the Inspector, I can see it is being served with a content type of binary/octet-stream.

How do I make sure the file has the correct content type when retrieving?

Comment: Which API client are you using? You need to set the `Content-Type` metadata on the object.

Comment: I am upload the file by simply pushing it to "gs://<bucket-name>/image.png" via the PHP function imagepng. I can't see anyway to set the content type specifically?

Comment: While not recommended, you can alter the content type by calling stream_context_set_default() right before the image is created, and then restore it afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

When using the [GCS PHP Filesystem Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/), you can set the `Content-Type` of the uploaded object using the file options parameter. There is [an example of it in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/#simple_file_write):

```
$options = ['gs' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain']];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents('gs://my_bucket/hello.txt', 'Hello', 0, $ctx);
```

Comment: I'm not using file_put_contents though

Comment: I'm using the "imagepng" function